# What pitch is 14-pin header adapter

Tags: pcb, connector, test-equipment, isp, mips

the device PCB have serial console port header and 14-pins test points right next it.
It marked as J303, J304. The device processor is MIPs based, so I assume that could be a 14-pins MIPS JTAG header. Its not clear, why it separated into the two parts J303/J304?
Or this is not a JTAG header? Then, standard MIPs programmer cable header have 2mm pitch, but this header on PCB is definitely smaller, the total length of connector shape is 14 mm. What pitch have this header? Then, how to connect this header to standard programmers cable header 2.0mm pitch?  I haven't seen such adapters anywhere.
[image]

Comment: A common pin pitch for this type of connectors is 1.27 mm. Although this doesn't look like the typical 14 pin JTAG pinout, as it looks like the top left and bottom right pins are connected to the ground plane.

Comment: measuring it is the better way to know the pitch (*not always easy*) but it is the only sure way to get pitch *measure from center of each holes* , for the rest @Klas-Kenny already sayed

Comment: If the question is about the pitch, why can't you measure it? Maybe you can use a compass if the access is really bad. As already stated in the previous comment, 0.1 inches (1.27 mm) is usual

As for the JTAG part, my experience is that there is no de facto standard cable. J303 and J304 in the photo seem to be two separate connectors, and even their orientation seems to be different as hinted by pin 1 (the small square). My bet is that J304 can be a JTAG, since you only need 4 signals, so the top of the connector would be JTAG plus VREF and the botton would be all GND.

Comment: 0.1inch = 2.54 mm

Comment: Add some wires to a standard header and then solder it to the pins. Problem solved.

Comment: measured with plastic caliper (not professional): ~1.5mm between centres of holes. Where to get such pin header and adapter for 2mm header?

Comment: Don't try to measure pitch between two near holes. Measure between two furthest in a row and divide.

Comment: 1.27 mm pitch = 50 mil pitch.  That is one of of the often used pin spacings for headers & connectors.  1.50 mm pitch would be be an outlier, or oddball connector.

Comment: @Maple, if measure this way, the pitch is 1.71mm (12mm : 7)

Comment: That's because you divide by 7. The pitch is 2mm (12/6)